# Wich is more performant: one single table in relationship with a lot of other tables or one single table with an intermediary table?

Tags: performance, database-design

I am designing a database where a table entity `Interaction` is in a 1-1 relationsip with a lot of other entities for example Appfollow_Metadata, Cloudtalk_Metadata etc... and these entities may reach 50. Currently I setup the design as such where `Interaction` entity has two 1-1 relationships:

```
 @Field(() => AppfollowMetadata)
  @JoinColumn()
  @OneToOne(() => AppfollowMetadata, {
    eager: true,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    cascade: true,
  })
  appfollow_metadata: AppfollowMetadata;

  @Field(() => CloudtalkMetadata)
  @JoinColumn()
  @OneToOne(() => CloudtalkMetadata, {
    eager: true,
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
    cascade: true,
  })
  cloudtalk_metadata: CloudtalkMetadata;
}
```

Each time i add a new metadata entity, I will add the relationship to the interaction entity. I am thinking of changing this approach and create a joint table with the following column `"interaction_id"` `"metadata_type"` `"metadata_id"` and in my interaction entity I would only add metadata_id and join the relation on this.

I am wondering about two things. Is this approach more performant than having 1 entity with a lot of relationships and ids and whether it is reliable as well.

**Current Schema:**
[image]

I plan on adding a lot of metadata tables later. Each interaction entity can have one metadata entity of any kind.

**Proposed Schema:**

[image]

This schema requires a bit more work for queries since I am using an ORM and it might be harder to maintain I suppose. I would like to know if such scheme is considerably more performant than the previously mentioned since the interaction entity will contain less columns.

Comment: Which database system? Please add some sample data for a few of the main Tables and for the new proposed Table, to clarify what you're asking. Performance is more dependent on what your use cases are going to be, but we can at least tell you if your proposed architecture makes sense.

Comment: @J.D. Done added.

Comment: @J.D. Any ideas?